# Can I patch a tiny part of the kernel without recompiling?

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, patch-management, inotify

I'm using inotify for a project, and desperately require the functionality provided by this patch: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/758183

Can I apply this patch to my existing Linux kernel, or would a recompile be in order?

Answer (score 1):

That is a patch to the Linux VFS. You will have to recompile the kernel, even if you eventually use ksplice to insert it into the running kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Could you please walk me through how to do this without trashing my system? I'm on debian and have the 'linux-source-2.6.26' package installed (sources in /usr/src/linux-source-2.6.26.tar.bz2)

Comment: I know nothing of how Debian handles its kernel source, but when you find the appropriate `fs/inotify.c`, go into the directory containing `fs/` and run `patch -p 1 < somefile.patch`, then compile as per Debian instructions.

Comment: If you want to use ksplice as per Ignacio's suggestion this may be a good place to start: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-spunix_ksplice/ (Updating Custom Kernels).